# English name and references for a combinatorial puzzle from Japan

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, terminology, puzzle

I am looking for the name and references of the following puzzle.

There are n intersecting circles in a row.
At the center of the circle and at the intersection of the two circles, fill the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 2n-1.
The number at the intersection should be the sum of the numbers at adjacent two centers.

An example for n=2:

[image: An image for n=2]

An example for n=3:

[image: An image for n=3]

The case for n=4:

[image: An image for n=4]
(A,B,C,...,G) is a permutation of (1,2,3,...,7) satisfying A+C=B, C+E=D, E+G=F.

This puzzle is called "連環の数" in Japanese language.
(Pronunciation is "ren-kan-no-kazu". "ren" means "linked". "kan" means "circle" or "ring". "no" means "of" etc. "kazu" means "number".)
I asked the site owner who uses this Japanese name, but he said he did not know any references and English name.
I would like to discuss or to publish a certain combinatorial property of this puzzle in English, but I am having trouble finding the name and references.
Thank you for reading.

**PostScript:** Unfortunately, it was determined to be off-topic. Can I repost the same question on puzzling.SE?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I have replaced urls to embedded images, and added pronunciation and character-based meaning.

Comment: Do you have any reference for studies about this puzzle? Are there always solutions? Do we know all of them? etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on puzzling.SE, not here.

Comment: the combinatorial problem does seem to have some mathematical depth (see Desiderius's comment), justifying MO as an alternative to puzzling.SE

Comment: With such a nifty structure it seems a shame to leave it linear. Studying this on graphs or hypergraphs sounds like a blast... *goes off with pencil and paper*

Comment: I would translate 連環 as linked rings, which are a thing, and the whole phrase as "linked ring numbers".  I think you could either do this and/or use the Japanese name.

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus For small n, I have counted all solutions using a program by brute-force search. If n=5, the number(#) of solution=6.
If n=10, #=7748. If n=15, #=52558620.

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus Actually, I have found a special solution for all n. I would like to publish it, but proper name is not found.

Comment: As a heads-up, I've asked a related (and directly inspired) question on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246837/linking-rings-and-labeling-graphs

Answer (score 8):

Tsuyoshi Uema refers to it as a "renkan" puzzle, and has written some code to solve small instances at http://prolog.web.fc2.com/src_017_renkan.html

Comment: Compare the name "renkan" with "renban lines" used as an English term in variant Sudoku puzzles. (A "renban line" is a set of cells connected orthogonally or diagonally, which contain a set of consecutive digits, once each, in any order)

Comment: right, linked squares instead of linked circles; so we might call this circular Sudoku?

Comment: Not really IMO. Renban lines don't have any internal constraints like the OP's puzzle. They are additional constraints to the normal Sudoku rules, for example as an alternative to given digits in the puzzle grid.

Comment: That page is entirely in Japanese, and he doesn't discuss the problem in English.

Comment: @Kimball Well, the URL and the computer code contain "renkan" in Latin letters. Although it also seems that "renkan" has also been used to refer to what is more commonly referred to as a [Chinese ring puzzle](https://ikuraexpress.co.za/products/nine-renkan-sudden-renkan-chinese-ring-de043-deepeyes-china-puzzle-puzzle-ring-japan-import).

Comment: @TimothyChow When Japanese write code or file names they often just transliterate Japanese words in the Latin alphabet (the text encoding is simpler this way).  So to me this doesn't really indicate that that person would call it a "renkan puzzle" in English.

Comment: @TimothyChow By the way, renkan by itself just means linking rings.  And to add to my previous comment, shorting the name for something in file names/compute code is a normal thing, both in English and Japanese.